# Infinitary logic—can infinite conjunctions contain themselves as proper subformulae?

Tags: logic

Can infinite conjunctions contain themselves as proper subformulae?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but with definitions like "If $\Phi$ is a set of formulae of $\mathcal{L}\kappa$$\omega$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$, then $\bigvee\Phi$ is in $\mathcal{L}\kappa$$\omega$" I'm not seeing what rules it out.

Comment: Please note that the title is not part of the question, and many people begin reading below the title. So the question itself needs to repeat any vital information from the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulae in $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa\omega}$ are built up inductively. For each $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}_{\kappa\omega}$ we can inductively define the set $S_\varphi=\{S_\psi : \psi \mbox{ is a proper subformula of } \varphi\}$.

A $\varphi$ as you've proposed would give $S_\varphi\in S_\varphi$, violating foundation.

Comment: Oh duh. We also can't have a VΦ with VΦ(a/b) ∈ Φ where a occurs in VΦ, right?